# What types of libraries are used in System.loadLibrary()

Tags: java

Recently I've been going through the source code of a library and found this snippet of code:

```
if (osName.startsWith("Win")){
      if (arch.equals("x86")){
        System.loadLibrary("LIBWINPTHREAD-1");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBSNDFILE-1");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBGCC_S_SJLJ-1");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBMPG123-0");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBMETHCLA");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBMETHCLAINTERFACE"); 
      }
      else {
        System.loadLibrary("LIBWINPTHREAD-1");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBSNDFILE-1");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBMPG123-0");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBMETHCLA");
        System.loadLibrary("LIBMETHCLAINTERFACE");  
      }
    }
```

I want to know what type of libraries this code is loading, and why this code is needed.
Code taken from: 
https://github.com/processing/processing-sound/blob/master/src/processing/sound/MethClaInterface.java

Comment: They come from the same repository, for example https://github.com/processing/processing-sound/tree/master/library/windows64

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca thanks for the help. Do you have an idea what System.loadLibrary() does in general, what type of libraries does it load?

Comment: Well, looking at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary-java.lang.String-) I take it that it's platform-dependent. For example `dll`s on Windows, `.so` on Linux, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here to use native code, meaning code that is not Java and does not require a JVM, wrote in a language like C, C++ (but there is other language that compile to native code). It's part of JNI, the Java Native Interface, which allow to use native code in your Java application.

*There is a project called [Panama](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/panama/) to make the use of native libraries simpler than the existing JNI which is quite complex and which might come in future versions of Java.*